# Show that there exists exactly one $l_A$-invariant $K$-subspace of dimension $1$ in $K^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, invariant-subspace

So I have this exercise where I want to check my solutions. Can someone help me?

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} a &b \\ 0& d \end{pmatrix} ∈ Mat_{2,2}(K)$ with $a, b, d ∈ K$, where $a ≠ 0$ and $d ≠ 0$. Let $l_A: K^2 → K^2$ be the corresponding $K$-linear map. A $K$-subspace $U$ of $K^2$ is said to be $l_A$-invariant if $l_A(U) ⊂ U$.

a) Show that if $a = d$ and $b ≠ 0$, then there exists exactly one $l_A$-invariant $K$-subspace of dimension $1$ in $K^2$.

So I have read that the condition for existence of a 1-dimensional invariant subspace is expressed as: $A\mathbf {v} =\lambda \mathbf {v}$, where $\lambda$  is a scalar (in the base field of the vector space.

This is basically an eigevalue problem.

So I have for a) $\det (\begin{pmatrix} a-\lambda &b \\ 0& a-\lambda \end{pmatrix})=(a-\lambda)^2=0 \Rightarrow \lambda=a$

We have therefore $\begin{pmatrix} 0 &b \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and this takes us to $v=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ which was what we had to prove.

Am I Right or am I doing something wrong?

Another question: If the problem was with another matrix and was to prove the existence of exactly one $l_A$-invariant $K$-subspace of dimension $2$, should we have proved that there are two independent eigenvectors?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Looks correct at first glance. I guess $K \in \lbrace \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C} \rbrace$? Also, in that case a two dimensional subspace is just $K^2$. So the notion of being invariant is somewhat trivial. But there are cases in which you can prove that there are two one-dimensional invariant subspaces.

Comment: yes my second question was in the case we were in $K^n$ where $n > 2$